# Published messages are consumed by a singleton orchestration in Biztalk 2006

Tags: singleton, biztalk, zombie-process

I have a singleton orchestration which concatenates the incoming messages. When the number of incoming messages is large, it throws an error after around 2000 messages that "The instance completed without consuming all of its messages. The instance and its unconsumed messages have been suspended."

Normally this is a zombie message error associated with singleton orchestrations, but we are dropping all the XMLs instantly which are published to message box using a FILE adapter.

Since messages are already present in Message box, why are we still getting a zombie message error.

Also, why does this always breaks at around 2000 messages? Is there any threshold associated with this?

Thanks 
Pulkit

Comment: Is the Delay Shape based on a specific time, like 5 minutes *from now* or a TimeSpan, which would get reset in eash loop.

Comment: As @boatseller asked, what is the Orchestration exit criteria?

Comment: The orchestration exit criteria is a flag which is set to false when the time is elapsed without receiving a xml message.

Comment: Also the wait time is a time span like 'new System.TimeSpan(0,0,1,0)'.
Time span is 1 minute.